# kohana3.3 Route::url() not working very well

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

```

route setting:

```
Route::set('home', '(<action>)(_<p>.htm)', 
           array(
               'action' => '(movie|tv|new)', 
               'p' => '[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+'
           )
)->defaults(
           array(
               'controller' => 'Home', 
               'action' => 'index', 
               'p' => 1
           )
);
```

get a url by Route::url():

```
Route::url('home',array('action' => 'movie', 'p' => 3));
```

got a url:

```
http:// www.domain.com/movie_3.htm
```

working very well.

but

```
Route::url('home',array('action' => 'movie'));
```

got a url:

```
http:// www.domain.com/movie_1.htm
```

this is not right .

it should be:

```
http:// www.domain.com/movie/
```

```

how can i fix it ????

thanks.

=====update 8/19 16:23 =====

```
Route::set('test', 'movie(_<p>.htm)', 
                array('p' => '[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+')
          )->defaults(
                array('controller' => 'Movie', 'action' => 'index', 'p' => '1')
          );
```

this route setting works well in any situation

```
Route::url('test',array('p'=>'1'));
```

got a url:

```
http://www.domain.com/movie

Route::url('test',array('p'=>'2'));
```

got a url:

```
http://www.domain.com/movie_2.htm

Route::url('test');
```

got a url:

```
http://www.domain.com/movie
```

= =,is there a bug in kohana core ???

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove "p" parameter from defaults and validators. So your code should looks like this:

```
Route::set('home', '(<action>)(_<p>.htm)', 
           array(
               'action' => '(movie|tv|new)'
           )
)->defaults(
           array(
               'controller' => 'Home', 
               'action' => 'index'
           )
);
```

I am not pretty sure about removing `p` from defaults so you can try to add it back

Comment: Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Required route parameter not passed: p

Comment: remove this line: 'p' => '[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+'

Comment: thanks but "Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Required route parameter not passed: p"

Comment: i  change "(<action>)(_<p>.htm)" to "<action>(_<p>.htm)". the problem has been solved .and i need a new route for empty path_info ....

Comment: Perhaps try `(<action>(/_<p>.htm))`. Your current route leaves the meaning of the first parameter passed in the URL ambiguous. This will force kohana into only accepting `<p>` when the action is also set.